# jasmine and angularjs mock multiple level of dependency

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, dependency-management

I am new to angular and jasmine and trying to write unit tests to existing code. 
I have a ajax service that depends on a common class which depends on a logger object.
I need help on how to create mock dependencies in my jasmine unit test code. The code below is a stripped version of original code just to have the necessary structure.

The ajax service looks like this:

```
angular.module('my.app.services').factory(serviceId,
    ['common', 'datacontext', 'profileService', 'programsService']);

function programsService(common, datacontext, profileService) {
    var logHttp = common.logger.getLogHttpFn(serviceId);
var service = {
.....
....
return service;
}
```

The service depends on common class which depends on logger.
The common code is like this

```
var commonModule = angular.module('common', []);

commonModule.provider('commonConfig', function () {
this.$get = function () { 
....
};
});

commonModule.factory('common', ['$q', '$location', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$window',  '$filter', 'omniture', 'logger', common]);

function common($q, $location, $rootScope, $timeout, $window, $filter, omniture, logger) {
    var service = {
....
};

    return service;
});
```

The logger class is like this:
    angular.module('common').factory('logger', ['$log', logger]);

```
function logger($log) {
};
return service;

function getLogHttpFn(moduleId, severity, showAlertByDefault) {
};
});
```

This is how I am creating the mocks:

```
 module('du.app.services','common', function ($provide) {
        //common doesn't have any methods, it has a constructor.
        loggerMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('logger', ['getLogHttpFn']);
        commonMock = jasmine.createSpy('common',['logger']);
        dataContextMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('datacontext', ['GetQ']);
        profileMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('profileService', ['GetProfile']);

        $provide.value('logger', loggerMock);
        $provide.value('common', [loggerMock,commonMock]);
        $provide.value('datacontext', dataContextMock);
        $provide.value('profileService', profileMock);
    });
```

This doesn't work I get error : Undefined is not an object. Evaluating common.logger.getLogHttpFn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mock multiple levels of dependencies.

If your service uses `common`, like this:

```
angular.module('my.app.services')
    .factory(serviceId, ['common', programsService]);

function programsService(common) {
    var logHttp = common.logger.getLogHttpFn(serviceId);
    // .....
}
```

Then the furthest dependency you mock is `common`. Use a plain object as the mock. So the start of the tests should look like this:

```
var commonMock = {
    logger: jasmine.createSpyObj('logger', ['getLogHttpFn'])
};

// is the same as
// var commonMock = {
//     logger: {
//         getLogHttpFn: jasmine.createSpy('getLogHttpFn')
//     }
// };

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('common', commonMock);
});
beforeEach(module('my.app.services'));
```